# Covering Number of $C^m\left[ 0, 1 \right]$ in $L^2 \left[ 0, 1 \right]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $m$ be a positive integer, for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, denote $N(\epsilon)$ the covering number of $C^m\left[ 0, 1 \right]$ in $L^2 \left[ 0, 1 \right]$, i.e., the smallest positive integer $N$ such that there exists $N$ functions $f_1, \cdots, f_N$ in $C^m\left[ 0, 1 \right]$, whose $m$-th derivatives are uniformly bounded by $M$, s.t. for any $f \in C^m\left[ 0, 1 \right], \lVert f^{(m)} \rVert \leq M$,
\begin{equation}
\exists 1 \leq i \leq N, \lVert f-f_i \rVert_{L^2} \lt \epsilon.
\end{equation}
I conjecture that $\log N(\epsilon)$ is approximately $C_0 \epsilon^{-\frac{2}{2m-1}}$ and I believe that there must be some previous results on it, but I didn't find any.